# Kendo NumericTextBox and MaskedTextBox AOT issue

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

While AOT compiling the project with Kendo Angular2 NumericTextBox and MaskedTextBox, following error occurs:

1. maskedtextbox.component.ngfactory.ts:275:35: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
2. maskedtextbox.component.ngfactory.ts:279:35: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
3. maskedtextbox.component.ngfactory.ts:283:35: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
4. numerictextbox.component.ngfactory.ts:203:41: Property 'widgetClass' is private and only accessible within class 'NumericTextBoxComponent'
5. numerictextbox.component.ngfactory.ts:208:41: Property 'numericClass' is private and only accessible within class 'NumericTextBoxComponent'

6.numerictextbox.component.ngfactory.ts:242:48: Property 'hostBlur' is protected and only accessible within class 'NumericTextBoxComponent' and its subclasses.

Here is my package.json entries:

```
    "@angular/common": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "0.14.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "0.14.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "0.24.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "0.9.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "0.7.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "0.15.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-upload": "0.12.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "0.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-popup-common": "0.3.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "0.18.2",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "2.11.4",
    "@telerik/kendo-dropdowns-common": "0.2.0",
    "@telerik/kendo-intl": "0.12.0",
    "@telerik/kendo-theme-default": "1.32.0",
    "@telerik/kendo-draggable": "1.5.1",
    "@telerik/kendo-inputs-common": "2.1.0",
```

AppModule imports

```
import { DialogModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dialog';
import { DropDownsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns';
import { PopupModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-popup';
import { IntlService } from '@progress/kendo-angular-intl';
```

Another Module imports

```
import { GridModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';
import { UploadModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-upload';
import { InputsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-inputs';
```

Answer (score 0):

Why all the telerik packages? You probably don't need those. Could you also share your app.module.ts file?

You should use only the @progress package and declare this in your app.module.ts :

```
import { InputsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-inputs';
```

edit: Answered too fast, they are dependancies for the progress packages. You shouldn't put them in your packages.json, though, as they will be installed automatically by npm as dependancies.

Answer (score 0):

I am having this problem as well (or something very similar). I can not run the JIT version of my application (using "npm start" with the lite server) or build the application into an AOT version. I'm not even using the masked textbox anywhere in my application. The only reason I have inputs installed at all is for the slider.

Anyhow, I can understand the build causing errors if something is wrong in the factory component but I do not understand why running the JIT version would be an issue. Maybe since the AOT folder resides within my root npm installed application folder everything gets JIT compiled on npm start?

I was able to get the JIT version running by deleting the following files:

```
AOT\app
AOT\@progres 
AOT\@telerik
```

I cannot however build the application.  When I attempt, I get the following:

1. Error at
   C:/Dashboard/aot/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs/dist/es/slider/slider-ticks.component.ngfactory.ts:87:7:
   Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
2. Error at
   C:/0/Health/Dashboard-lite/aot/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs/dist/es/slider/slider.component.ngfactory.ts:207:7:
   Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

Examining the slider-ticks.component.ngfactory, the error looks like this:

[image: slider-ticks.component.ngfactory.ts]

Hopefully this helps to eventually solve the problem...

Answer (score 0):

getting the same error. i modified the file numerictextbox.component.d.ts to remove private/protected from the 3 declaration. and made type of widgetClass and numericClass to any to make aot build work
can these be ignored?

Error at 
App/aot/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs/dist/es/numerictextbox/numerictextbox.component.ngfactory.ts:195:41: Property 'widgetClass' is private and only accessible within class 'NumericTextBoxComponent'.
Error at 
App/aot/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs/dist/es/numerictextbox/numerictextbox.component.ngfactory.ts:200:41: Property 'numericClass' is private and only accessible within class 'NumericTextBoxComponent'.
Error at 
App/aot/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs/dist/es/numerictextbox/numerictextbox.component.ngfactory.ts:214:48: Property 'hostBlur' is protected and only accessible within class 'NumericTextBoxComponent' and its subclasses.